# Commerce File - Error

Tags: commerce, debugging

I got the following Error when a licensed commerce file should be shown in the "Files" tab of the user account:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in commerce_file_handler_field_download_limit->pre_render() (line 27 of /web/websites_aip/atticindependent.ch/drupal/sites/all/modules/commerce_file/includes/views/handlers/commerce_file_handler_field_download_limit.inc).

I can reproduce this locally and some time ago it worked fine. The error doesn't appear in any search engine research ...

Any suggestions?

The Error was caused by a misconfiguration in the File Attache and Filesystem section. This case is closed. Thank you!